# Is there any way to interrupt my AirPods reading me a new text message?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications, airpods

A lot of times I'll hear my iPhone start announcing a text message through my AirPods, and want to "cancel" it for some reason (I already saw the notification on my computer, I'm in the middle of a good song, I don't care about the text, whatever).

**What I've Tried**

Pressing the power button once does nothing. Pressing it twice quickly activates Apple Pay as normal. Pressing it twice with a gap in between *does* cancel the notification as desired, but takes annoyingly long.

Answer (score 0):

A single short press (often mapped to “Play”) on the stem of an Air Pod should stop Siri from reading the notification and resume the content you were previously listening to.

[Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210406) doesn’t mention this, but it works on my iPhone with AirPods.

Answer (score 0):

Often the simplest method is the best. Remove the AirPods from your ear(s) temporarily. The proximity sensors then stop the playback while you pair them with your watch, computer or just disable that “feature” on the iPhone.

I’ve not had luck with play control on the headphones and when I don’t want to listen to a text, I also generally don’t want to listen to anything else. Just getting the speakers out of my ears is what works best for me.

Issuing a “hey Siri” also often works, but again - the time I have to cancel that - hope it plays what I want is usually better spent reaching up and removing one bud.

Over time, I’ve disabled these readings as they cause me more grief than pleasure and the times when they don’t work outweigh the few ones when it works. I rely on my watch and asking for a message now and am more satisfied than trying to control them.